# How to draw a contour plot when data are not on a regular grid?

Tags: r, datagrid, plot, contour

Say I have 3 variables such that

```
x=1:9
y=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
z=6:14
```

How can I rearrange the data so that I can make a contour plot of the data with r? 
I am getting the message

```
Error in contour.default(x, y, z) : 
  increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

Thank you.

Comment: I made z an array but I still wasn't succesful despite following Tyler's instructions. In the end I used contourplot() from the lattice library much easier to understand. See [Ajay Shah's explanation here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/108499.html "this") for details.

Answer (score 1):

`z` is a `matrix` of values where contour lines are to be drawn. `x` and `y` are their respective location. ["Tyler" at r-help mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg23971.html) explains this and gives an example of how to transform your data to make things work. See also examples in the help of `?contour`.

```
x = seq(0, 10, by = 0.5)
y = seq(0, 10, by = 0.5)
z <- outer(x, y)

contour(x, y, z)
```