# Contour plots in R

Tags: r, plot, contour

I have a dataset *countnp* with 3 columns as below:

```
>countnp
Time  Sections  Count
   0         0    370
   1         0      9
   1         1    127
   1         2    119
   1         3     55
   1         4     34
   1         5     55
```

and so on..The values of **Time** and **Sections** range from 0 to 7. Now, I want to create a contour plot of Time vs Sections, but I'm getting an error saying - *increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected*. Here **Time** and **Sections** both cannot be sorted at the same time. Please help me with this.
The code that I'm using:

```
>nplevel <- seq(0, 20, 2)
>contour(countnp$Time, countnp$Sections, countnp$Count, levels=nplevel)
```

Comment: google my friend, first entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847042/how-to-draw-a-contour-plot-when-data-are-not-on-a-regular-grid

Comment: I know how to sort the data. I would have done it if the three variables were independent, but they are not! I wanted to know how to make this work if the 3 of them are in a data set.

Answer (score 1):

The `contour()` function is expecting a matrix, `z`, as you can see in the help file or following the link that *MLavoie* provided.

Alternatively, you could use the `contourplot()` function from the `lattice` package, instead.

```
countnp <- data.frame(
  Time = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  Sections = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
  Count = c(370, 9, 127, 119, 55, 34, 55))

library(lattice)
contourplot(Count ~ Time + Sections, data=countnp)
```